# Why was my memory breakpoint not triggered in OllyDbg?

Tags: ollydbg, pe, anti-debugging, protection

I am currently battling this protection on an 32-bit executable.

At some point during it's runtime, the protection gets the address of `DbgUiRemoteBreakin` and writes a `JMP` to `ExitProcess` as an anti-attach technique. I decided to place a memory breakpoint on write(I also tried access) on that location figuring at the very least I'd find out what piece of code alters the code. Upon setting the breakpoint I hit <kbd>F9</kbd> only for my memory bp to never be triggered, I tried multiple times. The code was altered, but my memory bp was not triggered. This is the first time that a memory breakpoint was not triggered for me. I am puzzled as to why this has happened. My only guess is that `DbgUiRemoteBreakin` is located in *ntdll.dll* and that is why guard pages don't work there.
There were also instances where I had a crash when I set a memory bp on that function.

However I am hoping somebody has encountered this and can explain more in depth. My ollydbg version is 1.10.

Comment: [Memory breakpoints in Ollydbg can be bypassed](http://waleedassar.blogspot.in/2012/11/defeating-memory-breakpoints.html)

Comment: Try using a newer version of [Olly](http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html) or [x64dbg](http://x64dbg.com/).

Comment: As your executable is 32 Bit you can use the freeware version of IDA Pro. x64dbg is another good tool but still a work in progress and the disassembly is not even at Olly's standards. If you have a Mac or Linux machine you could also try Hopper disassembler; very user friendly and powerful. By the way, have you tried setting a hardware rather than software BP?

Comment: The executable is heavily protected, only ollydbg has the plugins I need to run it correctly.

Comment: Try using some anti-debug plugins for Olly. -> [ScyllaHide](https://bitbucket.org/NtQuery/scyllahide/downloads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason why your breakpoint didn't get hit is because the protected file removed it.

**Edit**: If the breakpoint was hardware-based, then the protected file can use `GetThreadContext()`, erase the DR entries, `SetThreadContext()`. If the breakpoint was page-protection-based, then the protected file can use `VirtualProtect()`.

Comment: I am sorry, but you are incorrect. Memory breakpoints are not Hardware breakpoints. Only hardware breakpoints can be removed/changed via Set/GetThreadContext.

Comment: @farmdve, if Olly used VirtualProtect() to guard the page, then the protected file simply used VirtualProtect() to make it writable, removing the guard protection as a side-effect.  Try using the hardware break-on-write instead.  If that doesn't work, then it's because the protected file removed it.

Comment: The only problem with this theory is that subsequent `VirtualProtect` calls would break. In any case, testing this theory is much easier with the simple Ctrl-G for `VirtualProtect` / `VirtualAlloc` approach.

Comment: @zv_, why would subsequent VirtualProtect calls break?  Anyway, I just confirmed my theory with a crafted file.  It calls VirtualProtect() which removes OllyDbg's memory breakpoint.  It behaves exactly like what farmdve is seeing.

Comment: break on, not `break`

Comment: zv_, still not making any sense to me.  OllyDbg calls VirtualProtect() to guard the page, and then resumes execution.  The malware uses VirtualProtect() to make the page writable.  The guard is removed by this action, so the exception never occurs on the write.  The malware could even restore the guard afterwards if it wanted to.  The breakpoint should be placed on the call to VirtualProtect() instead.  Then the action would be obvious.